# Unable to prepopulate Core Data - Problems with Relations

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

i would add some Test-Data to my Core Data Database. But i have a problem with my relations here. When i try to add 2 Core Data Objects only on the first one the relations are correct (ill check this with a sqlite Viewer) - but i dont know, why?

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
    let newSubCraftCategoryObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("CraftSubCategory", inManagedObjectContext: context) as CraftSubCategory
    newSubCraftCategoryObj.text = "Test Sub Category"

    let newUnitObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Unit", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Unit
    newUnitObj.text = "m2"

    let newCraftObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Craft", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Craft
    newCraftObj.minServiceLife = 8
    newCraftObj.maxServiceLife = 12
    newCraftObj.unit = newUnitObj
    newCraftObj.craftsubcategory = newSubCraftCategoryObj

    let newCraftObj1 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Craft", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Craft
    newCraftObj1.minServiceLife = 7
    newCraftObj1.maxServiceLife = 10
    newCraftObj1.unit = newUnitObj
    newCraftObj1.craftsubcategory = newSubCraftCategoryObj
```

So the first "newCraftObject" is totally fine, but there are no relations to the category and the unit in my second object called "newCraftObj1"

Comment: What kind of relations do you have between your entities? Are they to many relationships or one to one relationships? What is your Core Data model? Do you have any console error message?

Comment: Hello. Every Craft has a "One to One" Relation to Unit and to Category. There is no error in the Console, or any Warning. The first CoreData Object is fine, but the others did not have the relations (but the Objects are still in the database) - so there is only a problem creating the relation.

Comment: I think you need to-many relationships of those types: unit relationship: `Craft <<--> Unit`, craftsubcategory relationship: `Craft <<--> CraftSubCategory`.